# How remove Preceding and succeeding Space and special characters in Regex?

Tags: regex

I have a string Preceding and succeeding Space and special characters as below

```
 @#(Prakash(*_!*
```

i want to remove Preceding and succeeding Space and special characters. How to do this in Regex?

Comment: For space its ok. For  Preceding and succeeding special characters, how can i remove it?

Comment: special characters in the middle of a string are valid ?

Comment: note that underscore `_` is not usually considered as special character. you should define "special characters"

Answer (score 1):

you can match it by

```
[^\s@#(*_!]+
```

see the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/XHBgne/1/)

or you can replace it by

```
[\s@#(*_!]+
```

demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/qA0tpP/1/)